# Twilio Error when placing phone call programatically

Tags: twilio

I have procured a phone number by signing up with https://www.twilio.com/.
Next, I've downloaded the C# MVC code from https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call-csharp-mvc.
Now when I'm attempting to create a phone call between 2 numbers,I'm getting the error alert "There was a problem calling you - please try again later".
I'm supplying the required "ACCOUNT SID","AUTH TOKEN" and "Twilio number" from the Web.config.
Please help !

Comment: Are there any messages in your [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger)? What is the code you are using? Are you creating the call from your Twilio number and to a real number? Have you used something like ngrok to tunnel through to the application you are working on?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?